# Query multiple instances of the same SQL table with different conditions

Tags: mysql, sql, database, join, pivot

So I have two tables with:

```
t1 = (submission_id,field_id,value),
t2 = (submission_id, other_fields....).
```

Now **t1** contains a bunch of things in value, i.e. *field_id = 8* gives **value = firstname**, f*ield_id = 9* gives **value = lastname** etc. What I want is a table with (submission_id,firstname,lastname,...).

What I have some up with so far is something like this:

```
SELECT (SELECT value FROM t1 INNER JOIN t2 ON (t2.submission_id = t1.submission_id) 
where field_id = 8), 
(SELECT value FROM t1 INNER JOIN t2 ON (t2.submission_id = t1.submission_id) where field_id = 9)
```

But this just gives me an error about the fact that there is more than one result to each sub-query. I could use union, but this obviously just gives me horribly stacked results.

Anyone have any better idea?

Comment: Why do you need the join to t2?

Comment: I actually don't...Good point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't need the join to t2 then do a self join:

```
SELECT t1a.submission_id, t1a.value firstname, t1b.value lastname
FROM t1 t1a INNER JOIN t1 t1b
ON t1b.submission_id = t1a.submission_id AND t1a.field_id = 8 AND t1b.field_id = 9
```

I kept the join on `submission_id` if this is the link between the 2 values.

Answer (score 1):

One solution that is quite scalable is to use conditional aggregation:

```
select
    submission_id,
    max(case when field_id = 8 then value end) firstname,
    max(case when field_id = 9 then value end) lasstname
from t1
group by submission_id
```

The advantage of this technique is that you can easily add more columns by extending the query with more `max(case ...)` expressions, so it scales better than the self-join solution.

If for some reason you also need to bring `t2`, then you can join and add columns from `t2` in the `from` and `group by` clauses:

```
select
    t1.submission_id,
    t2.other_field1,
    t2.other_field2,
    max(case when t1.field_id = 8 then t1.value end) firstname,
    max(case when t1.field_id = 9 then t1.value end) lasstname
from t1
inner join t2 on t2.submission_id = t1.submission_id
group by t1.submission_id, t2.other_field1, t2.other_field2
```